# Using index and match with multiple conditions in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following race car telemetry data in an Excel worksheet: [Telemetry data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfBhM.png)

In another sheet, I have a table which defines the start and end distances of each track section for each lap. I am using the following formula to work out the maximum lateral G for each corner of each lap based  on the section start and end distances and the telemetry data.
[Max lateral G formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46xqH.png)

I now want to determine the steering angle where the displayed values of lateral G occur. I have tried to use the following formula to find the corresponding steering angle between the defined start and end distances of each track section but it is not working. Note that AH is the steering angle column.
[Corresponding steering angle formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KotLW.png)

Comment: Search for examples of index and match on here.

Comment: I was kinda sure, they pay more ....
anyway, interesting, and was not able to figure out from the first glimpse, why it does not work, as formula looks OK (or kinda close), - can you please share bits of data for example?

Comment: I think you need to separate the match equation out of the index and just place that in a cell and see if it returns what you would expect. I agree with NoobVB that it is difficult to understand what you are doing just from pictures.